# Laravel, Mail sending more than expected

Tags: php, laravel

(Laravel 5.6.)

I have 2 enviroments, `qa` and `prod`.

In qa everything works ok, but in prod Emails are sending wrong.

The idea is to send emails to a list of emails that are an input of a user when something is triggered.
In other words, the "edit" view of a user looks like:

```
name:
password:
emails_list: // a string
```

In my app, I have a button that calls and `ajax` url and that url execute a function that have this code:

```
// $emails is an array of emails made from the $user model with 
// $user->emails_list (using 'explode' to convert the comma separated string into an array)

foreach($emails as $email){
    $email = str_replace('"', '', str_replace(' ', '', $email));
    Mail::to($email)
        ->send(new IntentosAgotados($user));
}


// and IntentosAgotados($user, $reporte) is:

class IntentosAgotados extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    protected $user;

    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject("[My App] - Some text")
            ->view('emails.someview',[
            'user' => $this->user,
        ]);
    }
}
```

If a user has 2 emails in the `emails_list` the wrong behaviour is like this:

- The first time that I call the function, one email is sent to each user.
- The second time, a new email is sent BUT also the same first email (because each emails has different info).
- So the 3rd time, is sending the new email, BUT also one email of each others two emails:

  1th,
  1th-2nd,
  1th-2nd-3rd,
  etc

White should be "just send one email to each users"

I'm not using queues for this, the emails are sending in the moment.

But everything goes ok in `qa` enviroment as I said. So my question is:

How could I track why is sending wrong the emails? a log? or should I put some `dd()` around my code to see what's is happening and why is trigger in more than expected the `mail` function.

Comment: If you're adding to `emails_list` every time you send one, that's exactly what your code will do.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. `email_list` has always the same emails. My code is just sending one email to each of those emails. That part is ok, I want to know why is been resending each already sent email. And only in production, not in other enviroments.

Comment: While you're debugging this, you can change your `MAIL_DRIVER` to `log`. This will write the email content to the log file, rather than spam your users.

Comment: What do you mean the emails are sending wrong?

Comment: First check the `.env` file for both environments and check there isn't some `MAIL_` misconfiguration. Next check that the function isn't being called twice E.g. call the function from tinker with an `echo...` before the mail function.